# Downloadify with Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, downloadify

I'm using [Downloadify](http://pixelgraphics.us/downloadify/test.html) lib to download a text file on the client side in my `Angular` app

This is my function:

```
    function loadFileSaver() {
        Downloadify.create('downloadify',{
            filename: function(){
                return document.getElementById('filename').value;
            },
            data: function(){ 
                return document.getElementById('data').value;
            },
            swf: 'downloadify.swf',
            downloadImage: 'download.png',
            width: 100,
            height: 30,
            transparent: true,
            append: false
        });
}
```

My problem is with the line `downloadImage: 'download.png'`. It is giving `403 (Forbidden)` error.

Any idea on how to solve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check file properties of the 'download.png' file on the server to ensure it is accessible by the web user. (depending on what web server you are using)

try accessing the image by navigating to http://{yourHostname}/download.png

Comment: sorry, was missed there. I mean http: // your server /download.png . basically